# Rspec: Factory Girl & Complex Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, factory-bot

I am trying to test a helper method that would return the amount of `Subscribers` a `Campaign` is targeting. Being fairly new to TDD, I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how to write this one since the associations are quite complex. A `Campaign` "targets" by whether a subscriber is on the targeted `plan` and opted-in to the targeted `program`.

How do I get my Factory Girl objects to be associated with one another in order to continue writing the spec? As simple as it may seem, I can't get them to cooperate.

Here are the model associations..

**models/*campaign.rb***

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :program
    belongs_to :plan
end
```

**models/*subscriber.rb***

```
class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :plans, through: :plannables
end
```

**models/*plan.rb***

```
class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :subscribers, through: :plannables
    has_many :plannables
    has_many :campaigns

    validates :name, presence: true,
                uniqueness: true
end
```

**models/*program.rb***

```
class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :campaigns

    validates :name, presence: true,
                     uniqueness: true
end
```

**models/*plannable.rb***

```
class Plannable < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :plans
    belongs_to :subscribers
end
```

Here are the Factories..

**spec/factories/*campaign.rb***

```
FactoryGirl.define do

    factory :campaign do |x|
        x.sequence(:name) { |y| "201#{y} Example" }
        x.sequence(:comment) { |y| "The #{y} example" }
        channels ["Folder", "Fax"]
    end

    factory :program do
        name "Sims"
        comment "the sims program"
    end

    factory :plan do
        name "PDX"
    end
end
```

**spec/factories/*subscribers.rb***

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    sequence(:first_name) { |y| "Sam #{y}" }
    sequence(:last_name) { |y| "Sm#{y}th" }
    sequence(:email) { |y| "email#{y}@sub.com".downcase }

    factory :subscriber do
        first_name
        last_name
        email
        password "secret123"
        home_duid { SecureRandom.uuid }
        admin false
        sims true  #opt-in status
        cups false  #opt-in status
        tire false #opt-in status
    end


end
```

...and my specs..

**spec/helpers/*application_helper_spec.rb***

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe ApplicationHelper, :type => :helper do
    before :all do
        @program = create(:program)
        @subscriber = create(:subscriber, star: true)
        @campaign = create(:campaign, plan_id: @plan, program_id: @program)
        @plan = Plan.new(name: "STX)", subscriber_id: @subscriber)
    end

    describe "Campaign subscriber listing" do
        it "finds subscribers that opt-in to affiliated program" do
          expect(@campaign.plan_id).to eq @plan
        end
    end
end
```

Just as a starter, to simply test an association I created above via object ids, I added that first spec - yet I can't even get that to pass.. Any idea what I might be missing?

**Failures:**

```
 1) ApplicationHelper Campaign subscriber listing finds subscribers that opt-in to affiliated program
     Failure/Error: expect(campaign.plan).to eq plan

       expected: #<Plan id: 3, name: "PDX", created_at: "2015-06-16 20:51:18", updated_at: "2015-06-16 20:51:18", plan_id: nil>
            got: nil

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/helpers/application_helper_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**UPDATE**

I tried using Factory Girl `association` in my `campaign` factory..

```
factory :campaign do |x|
    x.sequence(:name) { |y| "201#{y} Example" }
    x.sequence(:comment) { |y| "The #{y} example" }
    channels ["Folder", "Fax"]
    association plan
end
```

But receive a confusing error...

```
* plan - Validation failed: Name has already been taken
```

I tried changing the name to something random but continuing getting this error.

Comment: Using `@instance_variables` is very heavy.
Prefer to use ```let(:program) { create(:program) }``` or ```subject(:program) { create(:program) }```.
`let` is lazy loaded.

Comment: @davidwessman - Thank you! I'll make those changes.

Comment: Do you think you can elaborate on your other question?

What do you want to do in your test?

Comment: @davidwessman - In the campaign `index` view, I'd like to show how many `subscribers` received each campaign. As I use TDD, I need to write a test that matches a `Campaign` object's association (plan and/or program) with a valid `Subscriber`. What I'm having issues doing is associating the Factory Girl objects so that the `@campaign` belongs_to the `STX` plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
campaign = create(:campaign, plan_id: @plan, program_id: @program)
```

Try changing to:

```
subject(:campaign) { create(:campaign, plan: plan, program: program) }
```

Would also work to do it with id's, as long as you are consequent.

**I made a typo here:**

```
subject(:campaign) { create(:campaign, plan_id: plan_id, program_id: program_id) }
```

**Should be:**

```
subject(:campaign) { create(:campaign, plan_id: plan.id, program:id: program.id) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown *how* your test it failing, which makes it a little difficult to help, but you're comparing a `plan_id` against a `@plan` object. Try change `@campaign.plan_id` to `@campaign.plan`.

Comment: Hey Andy, I made the change you proposed and posted the Failure Message above. It's pretty much the same I was receiving when using `@campaign.plan_id`.